# Outlook live ICS calendar off by 1 hour

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Test Cal
X-WR-CALDESC:2016-2017
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Toronto

BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Toronto
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Toronto
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20161106T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20170312T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE

BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20161020T235802EDT-7919w7sZDz
DTSTAMP:20161021T035802Z
DESCRIPTION:Details Sat Oct 15\, 2016 6:00pm - 7:00 pm
DTSTART;TZID=America/Toronto:20161015T180000
DTEND;TZID=America/Toronto:20161015T190000
LOCATION:Hockey Arena
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY:Game
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

This calendar when subscribed to in Gmail, iPhone or iCloud show the correct time of this even at 6pm. However Outlook Live displays this event one hour later : 7pm to 8pm. Why would this be? The dates and times are correct after daylights savings time change. So after Nov 5th, the times are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know where you got this VTIMEZONE definition but it has the DST starting only in 2017.
Try with something like:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Toronto
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
DTSTART:20081102T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
TZNAME:EST
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
DTSTART:20080309T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
TZNAME:EDT
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
```

I'm assuming that the empty lines were added only in your stackoverflow post.

Comment: yes i added them for readability. you are right DTS is of by a year!